# Cбой операции во время установки NLog.Configuration

Tags: c#, nuget, nlog

Cбой во время установки НЛог там говориться что оно уже установлено но как можно включить это в референсес в Visual Studio 2012
Идет попытка разрешить зависимость "NLog (≥ 4.5.8)".
У "NLog" уже есть зависимость, определенная для "NETStandard.Library".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: удалите все установленные пакеты NLog и установите заново

Comment: Спасибо и так же сделал но установил версией ниже и работал